# MySQL Query fails 'SELECT command denied to user...' but the user has permissions

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MySQL database where I created a new user account as follows:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'username'@'%';
```

Running a "SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'" confirms the permissions as:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'statstracker'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'passwordhash'
GRANT SELECT ON `database`.* TO 'username'@'%'
```

I can connect to the database and do queries from this user account when doing so via MySQL Workbench. I can even connect via MySQL Workbench from a different host on the network, but when I try to do so within my program, it fails with the following error:

> SELECT command denied to user 'username'@'hostname' for table 'tablename'

Here is my very simple test code:

```
String str = @"server=serverip;database=databasename;userid=username;password=password;";
MySqlConnection con = null;

try
{
    con = new MySqlConnection(str);

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM `database`.`table`", con);

    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dr["ID"]);
    }
}
catch (MySqlException err)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
}
finally
{
    if (con != null)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might be able to resolve this issue?

**EDIT: More Info**

If I don't try to do a select and just open the connection, the connection opens just fine:

```
String str = @"server=serverip;database=databasename;userid=username;password=password;";
MySqlConnection con = null;
try
{
    con = new MySqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Opened Just Fine");
}
catch (MySqlException err)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
}
finally
{
    if (con != null)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Also, I used the first code snippet (the one with the select) against a different MySQL Server on a different host, with a similarly created user account, and it worked. Does that mean my code is fine, and it's a configuration issue? If so, what sorts of things should I look at to try to work out what is going on?

Comment: maybe FLUSH PRIVILEGES? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-users.html

Comment: Thought of that, but as I'm able to connect from the workbench, the credentials are there... also, quoted from the page you linked: "With CREATE USER, FLUSH PRIVILEGES is unnecessary"... but thanks for the suggestion